Navigation to any view controller via Deeplink
I'm working on an app that receives URLs via Deeplinks, each containing a path to a specific view that needs to be opened. I'm exploring options to handle this efficiently, as manually navigating to each view using a large switch case seems cumbersome. Are there any existing solutions or frameworks available to streamline this process?

based on your question I understand that you do not want to the user to keep pushing until he reach his destination viewController. in that case uses unwind segue
